# Ajax call to WCF return "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation .."

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf

Using .NET framework 3.5.
I can't figure what's happening? My Get WCF services seem to be fine using the same approach.
Not sure, what's missing?

WCF:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        public void PutInventory(int caseId, DateTime dateReceived, string tamisCaseNo, string oarNo, string tin, string taxPdr, int oarTypeCd, string idrsOrgAssigned, string idrsTeAssigned, DateTime dateRequestComp, int tasCriteriaCd, string tasExpidateCd, DateTime dateEntered, string remarks)
        {
            InventoryDAL.PutInventory(caseId, dateReceived, tamisCaseNo, oarNo, tin, taxPdr, oarTypeCd, idrsOrgAssigned, idrsTeAssigned, dateRequestComp, tasCriteriaCd, tasExpidateCd, dateEntered, remarks);
        }
```

Ajax call my webform:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "Services/IVOOARInventoryService.svc/PutInventory",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: ({
                    caseId: '<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>', dateReceived: $("#dateEntered").val(), tamisCaseNo: $("#tamisCaseNo").val(), oarNo:  $("#OARNo").val(), tin:$("#tin").val(), taxPdr: $("#taxPeriod").val(), oarTypeCd: $("#oarType").val(), idrsOrgAssigned: $("#idrsOrgAssigned").val(), idrsTeAssigned: $("#idrsTeAssigned").val(), dateRequestComp: $("#dateRequestComp").val(), tasCriteriaCd: $("#tasCriteriaComp").val(), tasExpidateCd:$("#tasExpediateCd").val(), dateEntered: $("#dateEntered").val(), remarks: $("#remarks").val()
                }),
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("div#spinner").fadeOut("slow");
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    $("div#spinner").fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });
```

My error:

```
{"ExceptionDetail":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":null,"Message":"The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out, needed to use "JSON.stringify"

Example:

```
 data: JSON.stringify({
                    caseId: "18"
                    ...etc..
                }),
```

http://encosia.com/asmx-scriptservice-mistake-invalid-json-primitive/

Answer (score 3):

Set the content type to application/json

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "Services/IVOOARInventoryService.svc/PutInventory",
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            data: ({
                caseId: '<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>', dateReceived: $("#dateEntered").val(), tamisCaseNo: $("#tamisCaseNo").val(), oarNo:  $("#OARNo").val(), tin:$("#tin").val(), taxPdr: $("#taxPeriod").val(), oarTypeCd: $("#oarType").val(), idrsOrgAssigned: $("#idrsOrgAssigned").val(), idrsTeAssigned: $("#idrsTeAssigned").val(), dateRequestComp: $("#dateRequestComp").val(), tasCriteriaCd: $("#tasCriteriaComp").val(), tasExpidateCd:$("#tasExpediateCd").val(), dateEntered: $("#dateEntered").val(), remarks: $("#remarks").val()
            }),
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("div#spinner").fadeOut("slow");
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (json) {
                $("div#spinner").fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still getting the same exception

Comment: Try setting the RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json in your operation contract.

Comment: Already set, see posted code. Looking again, I am now getting: Encountered unexpected character 'c'.","StackTrace":"

Comment: I tried hard coding the values, not sure where the c is coming from?

Comment: You have set the ResponseFormat not the RequestFormat. Install Wireshark so you can monitor whats actually being sent. NOTE: Wireshark wont work on localhost communication.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Used Json.Stringify()